# SQL When a simple Join Fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to display product data, including product url information (page where the product can be found) in a document. On my development machine, I have a script that does this fairly successfully. The problem I am having is that when i move the same script fine on local, to a production machine, the code runs but only some products have their Url infomation displayed. The join is as simple as

```
Select 
    A.ID, A.Case, B.Val, B.Unit, B.Url
from A  
left join B on A.onID = B.UID
```

Any suggestions please on what the possible issue could be?

Comment: do you possibly have whitespace in the `ID` fields in your production environment?

Comment: The ID fields are uniqueidentifiers that are generated with newid(). Is it possible there could be white spaces in there?

Comment: @Kobojunkie probably not for a `newid()` field, are you sure that the `id` exists in both tables in production?

Comment: First, I'd check to see whether there's actually data where you expect it to be. It's pretty common for development and production environments to differ in surprising (and indefensible) ways.

Comment: Could you please post actual data from a record from each table that should be returned but aren't?

Comment: Data exist. It just is not returning the value from the table. And I have couple other issues similar to this happening on the production machine and trying hard to understand if code is the issue or some other thing.

Comment: It sure seems like the data is the issue. The SQL looks fine but without more knowledge of the data that underlies we will not be able to help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the failure looks like?  From your description, it seems that the type of the URL field is handled one way on the local machine and a different way on the server.  If I had to guess, the servers are configured differently.

Comment: What type are both columns used in the join condition? I mean, I realise that you've already said they are initialised with `newid()`. However, the question is whether they are actually `uniqueidentifier` (and not e.g. `varchar`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a left join I would expect  that some data would not have a URL since it comes from tableB which is not required to have data for the  records from table A to be returned. What this means is that every record in table A does not have an equivalent record in table B.